# Trying to get sliding images in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, dotnetnuke

I am trying to get sliding images (see the code excerpt underneath):

```
if(this.slidesCount > 1){
    // navigate "in" or "out"
    this.$slider
        .find('nav > span.sl-prev')
        .on('click.slitslider', function(event){
```

> 1. `Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'on'`
> 2. `Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 400 (Bad Request)`

I am getting above two errors in JavaScript. How can I solve the problem above?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: What is `'click.slitslider'`???

Answer (score 2):

Please try use jquery 1.7 and above. This method "on" is a new feature added in jquery 1.7 and above.
Are you using lower version like 1.6 and below was not supported.

Comment: Hi ... i am working on dot net nuke modules .. its loading version of 1.6.4 .. how can i change this ?

Comment: Use the above link comment by derek. Other wise refer this jquery site http://docs.jquery.com/Downloading_jQuery for your reference

Comment: Thank you for your help sir ..But its showing one more error the error is 1) Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 400 (Bad Request)